# How to run a Selenium IDE script in a WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, selenium, webbrowser-control

The following lines of code are part of a script that was recorded using Selenium IDE with Firefox.  When I play the script back using Selenium IDE it work perfectly.

```
        selenium.Open("/login.aspx");
        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_Content_Login1_Password", "xxxxxxxx");
        selenium.Type("id=ctl00_Content_Login1_UserName", "xxxxxxxxxxxx");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_Content_Login1_LoginButton");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Click("link=Time Clock Entry");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Click("id=btnPunch");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.Click("id=ctl00_Content_lnkLogout");
        selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

Is there a way to get this script run run in a webBrowser Control in a WinForm application?

Comment: I think you will need to use the web driver instead.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by telling the webBrowser control to simulate a click at a x, y coordinate.  I am controlling this by hard coding the number of pixels that make up the browser window.  This way it works on any resolution.  I am also controlling the screen location.